# Changing container height based on visible child (with Jquery)

Tags: jquery

I currently have a parent element that has children whom are positioned absolute. This destroys the height of the parent element, essentially, and I would like to add back the height based on the child that is currently being displayed (all children have different heights).

```
<button id="one">One</button>
<button id="two">Two</button>
<button id="three">Three</button>

<div id="parent">
<div class="child">height of 250px</div>
<div class="child">height of 500px</div>
<div class="child">height of 750px</div>
</div>
```

I have JQuery in place to show one of the children and add a class of, 'active' when you press one of the buttons. For instance: When you press button#one the first child shows and is given the class of, 'active'. The current JQuery that I have for height is:

```
var maxHeight = 0;
  $('.child').each(function() {
    if($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
      maxHeight = $(this).height();  
    }
  });   
$('#parent').height(maxHeight);
```

This only grabs and applies the tallest child's height (750px), when I would like the height to be dynamic based on what child is being shown and/or has the class of 'active'.

Comment: Hi Philip! So 3 containers (pos:absolute) inside container. You click 1st button - container changes it's height to 1st elements height. You click 2nd button - container changes height to 2nd elements height. Did I get it right?

Comment: Please, create a fiddle including you `js` and `css`

Comment: Why not let the browser do the heavy lifting for you?  Position your child elements as relative.  Add class "hide" to non active child elements which does a display:none.

Comment: Maybe position: relative is not possible in his situation. Without context it's hard to know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it's hard to understand your problem. I tried to guess it and create a snippet. I hope it helps!

```js
var parent = $('#parent');
$('[data-target]').each(function() {
  $(this).bind('click', function(){
    var elID = $(this).data('target');
    var elHeight = $('#'+elID).height();
    parent.height(elHeight);
    console.log(elID, elHeight)
  })
});
```

```css
#parent {
 border: 3px solid red;
}
.child {
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
}
.child:nth-child(1) {height: 20px; background-color: steelblue;}
.child:nth-child(2) {height: 40px; background-color: wheat;}
.child:nth-child(3) {height: 60px; background-color: firebrick;} 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-target="one" >One</button>
<button data-target="two" >Two</button>
<button data-target="three" >Three</button>
<div id="parent">
 <div class="child" id="one">height of 20px</div>
 <div class="child" id="two">height of 40px</div>
 <div class="child" id="three">height of 60px</div>
</div>
```

Comment: karlisup, I honestly do not know if I could explain my situation any better except for creating a demo example. You however, have answered my question regardless, so I thank you :)

Comment: Again, thank you, however, instead of '.bind' wouldn't using '.on' be a more up to date way to write the JQuery function?

Comment: If you use .bind syntax you can get in less trouble than writing .on. But there's no big difference ;). Glad I could help.